# ¡se puede ocultar (no eliminar) un valor en un listview Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

tengo el siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
String value = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String timestamp = snapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString();
                String id = snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString();

                arrayList.add(timestamp+"-"+id+"-"+value);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

se imaginaran que se ve horrible todo en un renglon por mas q lo separe por un guion, ahora se puede ocultar por ej: timestamp? pero sin q su info se vaya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto lo puedes realizar escondiendo la vista, dentro del método getView() determina que posición de la vista deseas esconder y cambia su visibilidad.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          
        ...
        ...

        if(position == posicionAEsconder){
           //Esconde vista.
           convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

---

Por cierto, como indica la documentación, para un enfoque más moderno, flexible y eficaz para mostrar listas, debemos usar `RecyclerView` en lugar de `ListView`.

Revisa: [**Cómo crear listas dinámicas con RecyclerView**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?hl=es-419)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, solo tengo un listview, el vie ni viewgroup lo tengo, deberia crearlo si o si cierto?

Comment: Esto se realiza en tu adapter "arrayadapter", debes de tener este método en esta clase.